# Resource.Id does not contain a definition for 'myRecyclerView' (Resource.Id.XXX)

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and firebase and my id myRecyclerView cannot be called in cs.
I was trying to findviewbyid via resources but I cant seem to call the id. My code is below.

this is the code for the deisgn. activity_main.axml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation = vertical>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id = "@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:background = "?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight = "?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme = "@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:elevation = "4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent">

            <TextView
             android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text = "Employee"
             android:gravity = "center"
             android:textStyle = "bold"
             android:textColor = "#fff"
             android:textSize = "18sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id = "@id/searchButton"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
                android:src = "@drawable/search"
                android:tint = "#fff"
                android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id = "@id/addButton"
                android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
                android:src = "@drawable/add"
                android:tint = "#fff"
                android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <EditText
        android:visibility = "gone"
        android:id = "@id/searchText"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight = "5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint = "Search"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:background = "#e2e2e2"
        android:id = "@+id/myRecyclerView"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my code in MainActivity.cs

```
    using Android.App;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Support.V7.App;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.Support.V7.Widget;

    namespace FirebaseSampleApp
    {
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        ImageView addButton;
        ImageView searchButton;
        EditText searchText;
        RecyclerView myRecyclerView;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.myRecyclerView);

        }


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, 
    [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
    grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
    }
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my codes? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the layout file(`activity_main.axml`) is not right,then the `Resource.designer.cs` file(which includes the generated id of kinds of resource, e.g. the id of view,layout file and so on) cannot be generated correctly.

We can found there are several problems in your `activity_main.axml`

1.change

```
android:orientation = vertical
```

to

```
android:orientation = "vertical"
```

2.when you add a id to a control,just add a `+`, just like this:

```
 android:id="@+id/searchButton"
```

Not

```
android:id = "@id/searchButton"
```

Meanwhile,make sure the images you used existing in the right place(e.g. `drawable` folder).( `android:src ="@drawable/search"` and `android:src = "@drawable/add"`)

**Note**:

After we code, we can just build the app, then there will have some error logs if our code have some problem.

So the whole layout file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation = "vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id = "@+id/toolbar1"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:background = "?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight = "?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme = "@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:elevation = "4dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent">
        <TextView
         android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text = "Employee"
         android:gravity = "center"
         android:textStyle = "bold"
         android:textColor = "#fff"
         android:textSize = "18sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
            android:src ="@drawable/search"
            android:tint = "#fff"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
            android:src = "@drawable/add"
            android:tint = "#fff"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<EditText
    android:visibility = "gone"
    android:id = "@+id/searchText"
    android:layout_marginLeft = "5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight = "5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom = "5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint = "Search"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:background = "#e2e2e2"
    android:id = "@+id/myRecyclerView"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I've done all you said but still my Resource cannot still find the id of myRecyclerView.

Comment: Yes. Several times. I even clean it before rebuilding it but the error CS0117 is still there.

Comment: I have upload a demo, you can check it here. https://github.com/jessiezh0320/AndroidDemo

Comment: If your problem still exists, could you please upload a demo so that we can test it on our side?

Comment: I found the solution. The nuggets needed to be in same versions. Thank you so much for the response!

Comment: If the answer is useful for you ,could you please mark it as an answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just be sure that all your nuggets are all updated in the same versions then rebuild the solution.